# Scale-to command beh for Pixellena image API

Tags: shimmercat, pixellena

I’m using the [Pixellena image API](http://pixellena.com/) and have an issue using the scale-to command for scaling an image. The same issue occurs both when using the demo page and with the SDK.
It doesn't matter if I use different output widths, I get the same problem, see below

[image]

I am using the below adjustments

```
"shifter": {
    "steps": [
            {
                "scale-to-width": 90
            }
        ]
    },
    "encoder": {
        "quality-measure": "fsim-c",
        "qual-threshold": 0.9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking Daniel. It is Vladir from Pixellena. Definitely this error message does not help at all. We have opened an issue to improve it. We'are also updating the doc, but probably there are yet old references elsewhere. In any case you can see [here](https://demo.pixellena.com/adjustments/), that now the `"scale-to-width"` changed to `"scale-to": {"width": 90}`, so if you give it a try using the `adjustments` as below:

```
{
   "shifter": {
        "steps": [
            {
                "scale-to": {
                     "width": 90
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "encoder": {
        "quality-measure": "fsim-c",
        "qual-threshold": 0.9
    }
}
```

it should work. If not please let me know and we will look deeper. Thanks a lot for asking. We appreciate your question, and that you're using our API.